# Multiple Checkbox Update and Delete Query

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to update **tutor table** and **tutor course table**, i have multiple checkbox for tutor course and if a teacher update his course or other info both table should also update.... tutor can increase or decrease course. I'm using following query but its not working for me

```
$update_content =   mysql_query("UPDATE wp_tutor
    JOIN wp_tutor_courses
    ON wp_tutor.tutor_id=wp_tutor_courses.tutor_id
    SET wp_tutor.tutor_name='$tNameVar',
    wp_tutor.tutor_qualification='$tQualVar',
    wp_tutor.tutor_skype='$tSkyVar',
    wp_tutor.tutor_specialization='$tuSAreaVar',
    wp_tutor.tutor_gender='$tuGenderVar',
    wp_tutor_courses.course_id='$tuCourseVar'
    WHERE tutor_id='$tid'");
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <caption>Tutor Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tutor ID</th>
      <th>Tutor Name</th>
      <th>Tutor Skype ID</th>
      <th>Tutor Specialization</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">Kashif</td>
      <td align="center">kashiflatif</td>
      <td align="center">Financial Accounting</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">Ammar</td>
      <td align="center">ammar.90</td>
      <td align="center">Research Methods</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">Bilal</td>
      <td align="center">bilalhaider95</td>
      <td align="center">Islamic Bond & Practices</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="float:left">
  <caption>Tutor Course Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tutor Course ID</th>
      <th>Tutor ID</th>
      <th>Course ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">6</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">
  <caption>Course Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Course ID</th>
      <th>Course Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">Certificate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">Diploma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">PGD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what happens when you run it? Any errors?

Comment: got a message that update successfully but no record update in database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$update_content =   mysql_query("UPDATE wp_tutor a
        INNER JOIN wp_tutor_courses b
        ON a.tutor_id=b.tutor_id
        SET a.tutor_name='$tNameVar',
        a.tutor_qualification='$tQualVar',
        a.tutor_skype='$tSkyVar',
        a.tutor_specialization='$tuSAreaVar',
        a.tutor_gender='$tuGenderVar',
        b.course_id='$tuCourseVar'
        WHERE a.tutor_id='$tid'");
```

Comment: this will update both tables because we are Joining by tutor_id

Comment: wel from your code I see you want to update only course_id on table wp_tutor_courses and all other updates are for wp_tutor.

Comment: My bad ... MySQL CAN update joined tables implicitly

Comment: then the problem is on your side sql version, etc. because I use that query on most of my projects and this update both tables. you can add WHERE a.tutor_id='$tid' AND b.tutor_id='$tid' to see if this works for you.